# Ruby: strip iframe and convert its src to a var

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, iframe

I'm trying to parse a string that has an iframe in it, convert its `src` attribute to a specially-formatted Ruby variable, then replace the iframe in the string with the Ruby variable formatted in a particular way. So far I've written this:

```
def video_parse(string)
  if string.include?('youtube.com/?v=')
    url = 'youtube.com/?v='
    string.gsub!('<iframe>.*</iframe>', video_service('YOUTUBE', vid(string, url)))
  end
  if string.include?('player.vimeo.com/video/')
    url = 'player.vimeo.com/video/'
    string.gsub!('<iframe>.*</iframe>', video_service('VIMEO', vid(string, url)))
  end
  string
end

def vid(string, url)
  string.split(url).last.split(/['"]/).first
end

def video_service(service, vid)
  "*|#{service}:[$vid=#{vid}]|*"
end
```

But it doesn't replace anything. I suspect my wildcard iframe tag selection is wrong, plus my `vid` method is a little clunky. How can I get my wildcard in `gsub` to work correctly? And for bonus points, can I write it a little more efficiently so I'm not parsing `string` to reformat the `src` in iframe?

**Update**

String looks something like this:

```
string = 'resources rather than creating our luck through innovation.\n<br>\n<br> \n<iframe allowfullscreen=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"311\" mozallowfullscreen=\"\" name=\"vimeo\" src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/222234444\" webkitallowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"550\"></iframe>\n<br>\n<br>\nThat hasn’t stoppe'
```

Second attempt looks like this, still doesn't replace anything:

```
def mailchimp_video_parse(string)
  if string.include?('youtube.com/?v=')
    string.gsub!(iframe) { video_service('YOUTUBE', vid(Regexp.last_match[1])) }
  end
  if string.include?('player.vimeo.com/video/')
    string.gsub!(iframe) { video_service('VIMEO', vid(Regexp.last_match[1])) }
  end
  string
end

def vid(iframe)
  iframe.split!('src').last.split!(/"/).first
end

def iframe
  '<iframe.*<\/iframe>'
end

def video_service(service, vid)
  "*|#{service}:[$vid=#{vid}]|*"
end
```

Still nothing.

Comment: Can you give an example of what `string` could be

Comment: Question has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit safer with Nokogiri:

```
d = Nokogiri::HTML(string)
d.css('iframe').each do |i|
  if i['src'] =~ %r{(youtube|vimeo).*?([^/]+)$}i
    i.replace(video_service($1.upcase, $2)
  end
end
puts d.to_html
```

(But note that it is *less* efficient than the pure regexp solution, as Nokogiri will parse the whole HTML.)

Comment: That's too perfect not to mark it correct. Thank-you!

Answer (score 1):

1. The `iframe` method should be `/<iframe.*<\/iframe>/` for it to be properly be recognized as a regex
2. The `Regexp.last_match[1]` should be `Regexp.last_match[0]` in the `mailchimp_video_parse` method
3. `split!` needs to be just `split` in the `vid` method (there is no `split!` method in Ruby)

Edited methods:

```
def mailchimp_video_parse(string)
  if string.include?('youtube.com/?v=')
    string.gsub!(iframe) { video_service('YOUTUBE', vid(Regexp.last_match[0])) }
  end
  if string.include?('player.vimeo.com/video/')
    string.gsub!(iframe) { video_service('VIMEO', vid(Regexp.last_match[0])) }
  end
  string
end

def vid(iframe)
  iframe.split('src').last.split(/"/).first
end

def iframe
  /<iframe.*<\/iframe>/
end
```

Comment: Dammit, of course. Although my `vid` method returns this error now: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass from (irb):359: in vid` so `Regexp.lastmatch[1]` must be returning the wrong thing.

Comment: The edits above will give you a result but it may not be what you are looking for, you may have to redo the `video_service` method